# Хранение мультиязычности и геолокация

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Меня интересует такой вопрос: чем чревато сохранение языка и локации в сессию?

Допустим,

```
if($_SESSION['lang'] =='') {
//Открываем модальное окно с выбором 
} else {
include_once = 'lang/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'/lang.php';
}
```

Типо такого или что лучше? Просто везде используют поддомены, как заметил. )

Comment: та пофиг. Главное сделать ссылки разные языки для поисковика

Answer (score 1):

[[@Сергей Румянцев](/users/13844/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2)](/users/13844/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2), Поддомены для разных языков я встречаю крайне редко. В большинстве случаем - это метка в URL, которая определяет язык. Относительно того, чем это "черевато" - ваш сайт будет проиндексирован только по одному языку, который будет по умолчанию.